# Как открыть диалоговое окно при закрытии приложения?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, pyqt, closeevent

Как при закрытии приложения спросить, закрыть ли приложение или нет?

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

class Main(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(423, 293)

        self.lineEdit1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("", self)
        self.lineEdit1.resize(321, 51)
        self.lineEdit1.move(50, 80)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)                        
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Import signal повесь колбэк

Comment: Опубликуйте пример программы, в которой вы хотите это сделать

Comment: S. Nick, опубликовал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> void QWidget::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
>
> Этот обработчик события вызывается с данным событием, когда Qt получает запрос на закрытие окна для виджета верхнего уровня из оконной системы.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):                 #(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(423, 293)

        self.lineEdit1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("", self)
        self.lineEdit1.resize(321, 51)
        self.lineEdit1.move(50, 80)
        
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(
                    self, 
                    "Exit", 
                    "Are you sure to quit?", 
                    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No,
                    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No
        )

        if reply == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
             event.ignore()
             

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)                        
    w = Main()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]